# The "XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task failed unexpectedly after adding Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps

Tags: android, xamarin, nuget

Been Having trouble building since I added the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps. Anyone else have issues lately? Same code set works on macOS, but not windows. :/

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Detail
>   Description Warning   IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the
>   project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the
>   failed project and projects that depend on it, have been
>   disabled. xyzMobile.Android       1   Active  To see what caused the issue,
>   please try below.
>
> 1. Close Visual Studio
> 2. Open a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt
> 3. Set environment variable “TraceDesignTime” to true (set TraceDesignTime=true)
> 4. Delete .vs directory/.suo file
> 5. Restart VS from the command prompt you set the environment variable (devenv)
> 6. Open the solution
> 7. Check 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\xyzMobile.Android_*.designtime.log'
>      and look for the failed tasks (FAILED)
>
> ---------------------------- Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       The "XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task failed
>   unexpectedly. System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory
>   record could not be found.    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode
>   mode, Boolean leaveOpen)    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode
>   mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)    at
>   Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>
> ### Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() xyzMobile.Android   C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets 135
>
> Done executing task "MakeDir". Done building target
>   "_ComputeAndroidResourcePaths" in project "xyzMobile.Android.csproj".
>   Target "_CheckForDeletedResourceFile" skipped. Previously built
>   successfully. Target "_ResolveMonoAndroidSdks" skipped. Previously
>   built successfully. Target "_ValidateAndroidPackageProperties"
>   skipped. Previously built successfully. Target
>   "_ResolveMonoAndroidSdks" skipped. Previously built successfully.
>   Target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" skipped. Previously built
>   successfully. Target "_XbdRestoreItems_playservicesbasement" in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.googleplayservices.basement\60.1142.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets":   Task "CreateProperty" skipped, due to false condition;
>   (Exists('$(AndroidSdkDirectory)\extras\google\$(_XbdAarFile_playservicesbasement)'))
>   was evaluated as (Exists('C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-basement\11.4.2\play-services-basement-11.4.2.aar')).
>   Done building target "_XbdRestoreItems_playservicesbasement" in
>   project "xyzMobile.Android.csproj". Target
>   "_XbdRestoreItems_playservicestasks" in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.googleplayservices.tasks\60.1142.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.targets":
>   Task "CreateProperty" skipped, due to false condition;
>   (Exists('$(AndroidSdkDirectory)\extras\google\$(_XbdAarFile_playservicestasks)'))
>   was evaluated as (Exists('C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-tasks\11.4.2\play-services-tasks-11.4.2.aar')).
>   Done building target "_XbdRestoreItems_playservicestasks" in project
>   "xyzMobile.Android.csproj". Target "_XbdRestoreItems_playservicesbase"
>   in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.googleplayservices.base\60.1142.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.targets":   Task "CreateProperty" skipped, due to false condition;
>   (Exists('$(AndroidSdkDirectory)\extras\google\$(_XbdAarFile_playservicesbase)'))
>   was evaluated as (Exists('C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-base\11.4.2\play-services-base-11.4.2.aar')).
>   Done building target "_XbdRestoreItems_playservicesbase" in project
>   "xyzMobile.Android.csproj". Target "_XbdRestoreItems_playservicesmaps"
>   in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.googleplayservices.maps\60.1142.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.targets":   Task "CreateProperty" skipped, due to false condition;
>   (Exists('$(AndroidSdkDirectory)\extras\google\$(_XbdAarFile_playservicesmaps)'))
>   was evaluated as (Exists('C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-maps\11.4.2\play-services-maps-11.4.2.aar')).
>   Done building target "_XbdRestoreItems_playservicesmaps" in project
>   "xyzMobile.Android.csproj". Target "_XbdRestoreItems_firebasecommon"
>   in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.common\60.1142.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Firebase.Common.targets":
>   Task "CreateProperty" skipped, due to false condition;
>   (Exists('$(AndroidSdkDirectory)\extras\google\$(_XbdAarFile_firebasecommon)'))
>   was evaluated as (Exists('C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\firebase\firebase-common\11.4.2\firebase-common-11.4.2.aar')).
>   Done building target "_XbdRestoreItems_firebasecommon" in project
>   "xyzMobile.Android.csproj". Target "_XbdRestoreItems_firebaseiid" in
>   file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.iid\60.1142.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.targets":
>   Task "CreateProperty" skipped, due to false condition;
>   (Exists('$(AndroidSdkDirectory)\extras\google\$(_XbdAarFile_firebaseiid)'))
>   was evaluated as (Exists('C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\firebase\firebase-iid\11.4.2\firebase-iid-11.4.2.aar')).
>   Done building target "_XbdRestoreItems_firebaseiid" in project
>   "xyzMobile.Android.csproj". Target
>   "_XbdRestoreItems_firebasemessaging" in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.messaging\60.1142.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.targets":
>   Task "CreateProperty" skipped, due to false condition;
>   (Exists('$(AndroidSdkDirectory)\extras\google\$(_XbdAarFile_firebasemessaging)'))
>   was evaluated as (Exists('C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\firebase\firebase-messaging\11.4.2\firebase-messaging-11.4.2.aar')).
>   Done building target "_XbdRestoreItems_firebasemessaging" in project
>   "xyzMobile.Android.csproj". Target "_XamarinBuildAddDownloadedItems"
>   in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets":
>   Done building target "_XamarinBuildAddDownloadedItems" in project
>   "xyzMobile.Android.csproj". Target "_XamarinBuildDownloadCore" in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets":
>   Using "XamarinDownloadArchives" task from assembly
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.dll".
>   Task "XamarinDownloadArchives"   Done executing task
>   "XamarinDownloadArchives". Done building target
>   "_XamarinBuildDownloadCore" in project "xyzMobile.Android.csproj".
>   Target "_XamarinBuildDownloadPartialZipsCore" skipped, due to false
>   condition; ('@(XamarinBuildDownloadPartialZip)'!='') was evaluated as
>   (''!=''). Target "_XamarinBuildDownload" in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets":
>   Done building target "_XamarinBuildDownload" in project
>   "xyzMobile.Android.csproj". Target
>   "_XamarinAndroidBuildResourceRestore" skipped, due to false condition;
>   ('@(RestoreAssemblyResource)'!='') was evaluated as (''!=''). Target
>   "_XamarinBuildDownload" skipped. Previously built successfully. Target
>   "_XamarinAndroidBuildAarRestore" in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets":
>   Using "XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore" task from assembly
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.dll".
>   Task "XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore"
>       Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\Debug\XbdMerge\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.dll.stamp
>       Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\Debug\XbdMerge\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.dll.stamp
>       Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\Debug\XbdMerge\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.dll.stamp
>       Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\Debug\XbdMerge\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.dll.stamp
>       Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\Debug\XbdMerge\Xamarin.Firebase.Common.dll.stamp
>       Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\Debug\XbdMerge\Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.dll.stamp
>       Reference has already had resources merged, skipping due to: obj\Debug\XbdMerge\Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.dll.stamp   Done
>   executing task "XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore". Done building target
>   "_XamarinAndroidBuildAarRestore" in project
>   "xyzMobile.Android.csproj". Target "_XamarinAndroidBuildAarRestore"
>   skipped. Previously built successfully. Target
>   "_XamarinAndroidBuildAarProguardConfigs" in file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets":
>   Using "XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task from assembly
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.dll".
>   Task "XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs"
>       C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018: The "XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task failed
>   unexpectedly.
>       C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018: System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central
>   Directory record could not be found.
>       C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
>       C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream
>   stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
>       C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream
>   stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding
>   entryNameEncoding)
>       C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs.Execute()
>       C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>       C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>   Done executing task "XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" -- FAILED.
>   Done building target "_XamarinAndroidBuildAarProguardConfigs" in
>   project "xyzMobile.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
>
> Done building project "xyzMobile.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018: The "XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task failed
>   unexpectedly.
>   C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018: System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central
>   Directory record could not be found.
>   C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
>   C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream
>   stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
>   C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream
>   stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding
>   entryNameEncoding)
>   C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs.Execute()
>   C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(135,3):
>   error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>       0 Warning(s)
>       1 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.72

Comment: [This](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100024/xamarinbuildandroidaarproguardconfigs-task-faild) is about XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs task faild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to clear the XamarinBuildDownloadCache. I believe somehow that got into a corrupted state. I also needed to do a factory reset on my emulators, though not sure if I needed to do that.